# What is "WalletPasses/1.2.3" browser user-agent?

Tags: http, security, user-agent

We've came across a strange user-agent string in our server logs. A browser (pretending to be an iOS Safari 9.0) had `WalletPasses/1.2.3` at the end of the `user-agent` HTTP header.

What's that device or software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search reveals https://walletpasses.io. From there:

> Wallet Passes allows you to use your Apple® Wallet / Passbook® Passes on Android™

So I'm guessing that they're spoofing the iOS Safari user-agent to make websites offer Apple Wallet to them.